# Grails: Generic hibernate version for plugin

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-plugin

I wonder if anyone knows a simple way of managing hibernate within a plugin so that the plugin then becomes compatible with all variations of hibernate configuration from within various types of grails default applications.

[Line 21 has hibernate :hibernate4:4.3.5.4](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L21)
This now appears to work fine with grails 2.4.2 apps but on grails 2.4.4 apps

```
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
```

This causes issues.

Just wondering if there is any way of making this more generic so it would even work with grails pre 2.4 apps..

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `":hibernate:$grailsVersion"`

Comment: thanks will try, from what I recall this is how it was done back in the days of grails 2.2 etc... For a start this is a test on grails 2.4.4 and it has //runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"   so in this answer this would equate to ":hibernate:2.4.4" which would not actually be correct since the default hibernate for 2.4.4

Comment: Im not sure tbh, but i don't think it work like you are saying. You can see things like ":tomcat:$grailsVersion" in the code of many plugins, and there is no such thing like tomcat 2.4. Check this: https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=nLqyHl_KfTQC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=build%28":hibernate:$grailsVersion"&source=bl&ots=UBr5xVVLTS

Comment: This does not work for tomcat or hibernate as of Grails 2.3, since we finally stopped the artificial practice of coupling these two plugins to Grails releases when there was no benefit from that. The versions are now based on the Hibernate or Tomcat version that they use